# How to use an API REST Symfony with my Ionic Capacitor application on Android Studio

Tags: android, symfony, ionic-framework, localhost, capacitor

when I try to run my application on Android Studio, the connection with my API REST Symfony don't working. It's my file capacitor.config.json, I have adding `"server": { "url": "http://localhost:8000/login" }`[screenshot file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15zqj.png)  I have a response with status code 200 OK (when it's work and don't), while that should send me back my user. [my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLsKo.png)
I use Capacitor on Ionic and I'm in localhost.

Comment: Your server is returning an HTML response instead of JSON, I think you are looking for json_login: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html

Comment: In my API, response format is in JSON `$user_ok = $serializer->serialize($user_to_store[0], 'json');

return new Response($user_ok, Response::HTTP_OK);`

Comment: Please provide some code and the response. The `<` in the error indicates an html tag  opening in the response. Also check the Content-Type of your response.

Comment: is it possible that the error comes from a file on Android Studio? because on my Ionic browser application no error...

Comment: Try to get the full response of the server that cause issue. Also you can check your symfony's log or watch the request in the profiler if the server is in dev mode.